# Small gaps appearing in UICollectionView section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Very strange issue on `UICollectionView`...

I have a `UIImageView` below a `UICollectionView` and I noticed there are multiple hairline / 1px clear lines appearing at certain points in the `collectionView`... one appearing below a description cell...

[image: first]

Assuming it was a problem with the cell, I've investigated every way I could think with no joy. I've doubled up this cell to illustrate the issue happens in between `IndexPath` **section 1** and **item 6 and 7**

Even when this cell is doubled up... the divider line cell below is part of the same `section` so it's definitely not a footer or a header???

[image: second]

My flowLayout is

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = .zero
flowLayout.footerReferenceSize = .zero
```

I made the background of the `collectionView` red to highlight the issue... I don't have a clue what the issue is.

View Hierarchy

[image: view]

**Update**

changing `flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0` to `-1.0` 'fixes' the issue in some places... why wouldn't this value remain accurate along all cells? and remain at 0.0??

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = -1.0
flowLayout.sectionInset = .zero
```

Comment: Does this problem occurs on simulator or real device ?

Comment: It appears on both sadly... I was hoping it was just simulator as well but alas not.

Comment: Can you please also include view's hierarchy ? (captured from UI viewer or via recursiveDescription: method)

Comment: Which view? It's definitely a problem with the spacing in between the collectionView cells... or somehow the height related to the flowlayout surely?

Comment: The main view (or window), which contains both `UIImageView` and `UICollectionView`.

Comment: How do I use UI viewer to print out?

Comment: It's 100% spacing... it's not a view.

Comment: Setting `minimumLineSpacing` to `-1.0` fixes the issue... :|

Comment: can you plz highlight which line you pointing at

Comment: huh? which line?? the red one

Comment: can you just take a screenshot of the entire view?

Comment: Why do you need a screenshot of the entire view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've only gone and solved it... hours after putting a 300 bounty on it..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

 // calculated CGSize...

  return CGSize(width:collectionView.bounds.size.width,height:ceil(calculatedHeight) 

}
```

remember @2x @3x always **ceil** your calculated cells... `UICollectionViews` can't hack 0.5 points

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer of @Magoo:

A `CGSize` structure is sometimes used to represent a distance vector, rather than a physical size. As a vector, its values can be negative. To normalize a `CGRect` structure so that its size is represented by positive values, call the standardized function.

In Swift 2.x you will need to use:

```
return CGSizeMake(width:collectionView.bounds.size.width,height:ceil(calculatedHeight)
```

As of Swift 3 you can no longer use `CGSizeMake`:

```
return CGSize(width:collectionView.bounds.size.width,height:ceil(calculatedHeight)
```

- The `ceil` function rounds a number UP to the nearest integer, if necessary.
- For rounding down you have `floor`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers and nothing was working for me. Finally, I ended up adjusting my collectionView width so that the number of cells evenly divided into it.

Which solved the problem for me.

```
// Adjust the width of the collectionView, so that our cells divide evenly into it
CGFloat widthModulus = fmod(collectionViewWidth, numberOfCells);
CGFloat newCollectionViewWidth = collectionViewWidth - widthModulus;
```